# If $P(A \ \cup \ B) = P(A) + P(B)$, is it the case that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint?

Tags: probability

I know that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events, then $P(A \cup \ B) = P(A) + P(B)$. However, is the converse true as well? Thanks.

Comment: Disjoint events in the sense of probability simply means $P(A \cap B) = 0$, not necessarily that *as sets* $A\cap B = \emptyset$.  For this reason (avoiding confusion) it is sometimes stated instead that $A,B$ are *mutually exclusive* events.

Comment: @hardmath, I don't agree with your definition of disjoint. Can you cite any references?

Comment: @hardmath I don't agree as well. *If* they are disjoint, then $P(A \cap B) = 0$, but the converse doesn't necessarily hold.

Comment: @TonyK: I'm drawing a distinction between the use of "disjoint" in probabilities and in sets, and suggesting to avoid confusion by using "mutually exclusive" instead of "disjoint".  The terminology that events $A,B$ are disjoint (while not ideal) is certainly tolerable where the probabilistic context is clear (esp. when there is no ascription of *sets* to the events).

Comment: @hardmath: I am asking whether you have any evidence for your claim that this is the default meaning of "disjoint" in probability theory.

Comment: @Clarinetist:  I understand the basis for your objection, but I'm trying to clarify the terminology in a sympathetic way.  Many elementary treatments will "abuse" the term disjoint in a purely probabilistic way as zero joint probability.  Google's first hit on "disjoint probability definition" is [This](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch05-rul.html): `Disjoint:   P(A and B) = 0`

Comment: @hardmath As you can see in that page, that isn't taken as a definition. Right before that line, "If two events are disjoint, then the probability of them both occurring at the same time is 0."

Comment: @hardmath: I looked at the first eight Google hits for "disjoint events". Of these, three gave a definition of "disjoint'; all three disagreed with your definition. I think you are outvoted :-/

Comment: Note that Comments are intended to clarify the Question.  Here the choice of terminology is open to interpretation and I was calling attention to the meaning of the term as crucial to giving a useful Answer.  @Clarinetist: I don't think your line proves that the line I quoted is not offered as definition.

Comment: @TonyK:  The process of clarification should be a sympathetic one.  I suggested a "better" term in my Comment.  Possibly you disagree with the use of "mutually exclusive" as well.  However you should then suggest what term *could be used* to better ask this Question.

Comment: As discussed, your equation implies $P(A \cap B) = 0$.  In probability, we don't necessarily say that these two events are disjoint, but we would say that they are disjoint *almost surely*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, all you can deduce is that $P(A \cap B) = 0$, because $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$ It doesn't mean that $A \cap B$ is empty.

Answer (score 7):

No for example suppose you have a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  Let $A=[0,1/2]$ and $B=[1/2,1]$.  Then $P(A\cap B)=0$ but $A\cap B=\{1/2\}\not=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you for coming up with an excellent counterexample! (+1)

Comment: Why is $P(A\cap B)=0$?

Comment: Because the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is continuous: the probability of any single particular point is $0$.

Comment: @Inuyaki If you have any continuous random variable X, $$\mathbb{P}(X = c) = \int_{c}^{c}f_{X}(x)\text{ d}x = 0$$

Comment: @Inuyaki Another way to see that $P(A \cap B) = 0$ is to note that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ for any subsets $A$ and $B$ of $[0,1]$ . Now $P(A \cup B) = 1$, $P(A) = 1/2$, and $P(B) = 1/2$. Plugging in these values reveals $P(A \cap B) = 0$.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: This is incorrect, disregard. The comments have valuable discussion and counterexamples.

Yes. Assuming $A$ and $B$ are independent, by definition, $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$. If we have $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$, then $P(A \cap B) = 0$, which is the definition of disjoint events.

Comment: Why do you need independence?

Comment: Hmm, is that true? Doesn't it just mean that $A\cap B$ has probability zero, not that it is empty. (Unless only empty sets have probability zero.)

Comment: Why do we need to assume that $A$ and $B$ are independent? What do you mean "by definition"?

Comment: Is that really the definition of disjoint events? What if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, $A$ is $(X \le \frac12)$, and $B$ is $(X \ge \frac12)$?

Comment: A counterexample can even be given on a finite probability space, e.g. if $X$ is a random variable with values in $\{1,2\}$, with $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=2) = 0$. Letting $A = \{ 1, 2 \}$ and $B = \{ 2 \}$, we see $A$ and $B$ are independent, non-disjoint events such that $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B)$.