# Does $P(A \cap B) = 0$ imply that $A \cap B = \emptyset$?

Tags: probability

Given that $P(A \cap B) = 0$, where  $A$ and $B$ are two events, does this   imply that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ ?

Is it not possible to have a probability zero for an event which is not empty?

Regards.

Comment: Yes, that is surely possible, depending on how things are defined.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1632072/1508) is a similar question (though not exactly a duplicate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An equivalent simpler way to ask the question is: if $E$ is an event, does $P(E)=0$ mean that $E$ is impossible?

In the discrete case (event $E$ is discrete, finite or countable) the answer is *yes*.

In the continuous case, the answer is *not always*. For instance if the distribution is continuous (normal, for example) then the probability of any countable event will be zero. As you may know, for a normal random variable, $P(Z=z)=0$ for any value of $z$ -- even though the event $"Z=z"$ is possible/nonempty.

This also works for probabilities that do not depend on random variables.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not imply it.
 Take $A=\mathbb{Q}$, the rational numbers inside $B=[0,1]$. Then $A\cap B=A$ has probability zero (with respect to the uniform distribution), but obviosuly $A\cap B$ is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

No. That depends on the probability space to be honest. For example if your experiment is choosing a point uniformly in the interval $[0,1]$ then the probability of every single point (actually of any countable subset of $[0,1]$) is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, if I pick a random number from $[0,2]$, then $P([0,1]\cap [1,2])=0$, however, $[0,1]\cap[1,2]=\{1\}\neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

For continuous case, let $f(x)$ denote the probability density function for random variable $x$ (*e.g. height, weight, etc*). Then probability of $x$ lying between $a$ and $b$ is defined as

$P(a\le x\le b)=\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

Now what happens if you find $P(x=a)$?